nesjs app can't connect to Postgresql via .env
The nesjs application cannot connect to Postgresql if use the .env file, when if  connect directly in app.module.ts everything works
\[Nest\] 1648  - 30.05.2024, 12:54:13   ERROR \[TypeOrmModule\] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)

With this connection everything works flawlessly:
  TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => {
          return {
              type: 'postgres',
              host: 'localhost',
              port: 5432,
              username: 'postgres',
              password: 'root',
              database: 'JoJo-db',
              entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
              synchronize: true,
          } as TypeOrmModuleOptions;
      },
  }),

An error occurs when connecting this way
I also tried to connect as described in the documentation, also an error
app.module.ts:
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService ) => ({
          type: 'postgres',
          host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
          port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
          username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
          password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
          database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
          entities:  [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
          synchronize: true,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService]
    }),

.env:
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_NAME=JoJo-db


I solved the issue, I just need to additionally specify the code that creates and initializes the new data source
ConfigModule.forRoot( {isGlobal: true} ),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService ) => ({
          type: 'postgres',
          host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
          port: +configService.get('DB_PORT'),
          username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
          password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
          database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
          entities:  [__dirname + '/**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
          synchronize: true,
      }),

      dataSourceFactory: async (options) => {
        const dataSource = await new DataSource(options).initialize();
        return dataSource;
      },
      
    })

